# Bootstrap navigation toggler is not closing menu in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am currently transferring my static website into WordPress.

The links in my bootsrtap navigation menu work fine. The burger menu animation also works fine, so this tells me that JQuery is working fine within WordPress.

However, the burger menu doesn't close when I click it. Does anybody have an answer to this?

HTML CODE:

```
<header id="header"> <!-- Start of header --> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg text-center navbar-light"> <!--   Sart of navigation --->
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html"></a>

        <!-- Toggler -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler first-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent20"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent20" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
        </button>

        <!-- Collapsible content -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent20">

          <!-- Links -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about-me.html">ABOUT ME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
        </div> <!-- End of collapsible content --->

      </nav> <!-- End of navigation --->
  </header> <!-- End of header --->
```

PHP CODE:

```
  <header id="header" class="site-header navbar-static-top <?php echo wp_bootstrap_starter_bg_class(); ?>" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl p-0 navbar-expand-lg text-center navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand"></a>
                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_logo' ) ): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_logo' )); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>">
                    </a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <a class="site-title" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>"><?php esc_url(bloginfo('name')); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- Toggler -->

            <button class="navbar-toggler first-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
            </button>

            <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_id'    => 'main-nav',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end',
            'menu_id'         => false,
            'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav',
            'depth'           => 3,
            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'          => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
            ));
            ?>

        </nav>
    </div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```